# Python distinguish between returned tuple and multiple values

Tags: python

I want to write a wrapper function which call one function and pass the results to another function. The arguments and return types of the functions are the same, but I have problem with returning lists and multiple values.

```py
def foo():
    return 1,2

def bar():
    return (1,2)

def foo2(a,b):
    print(a,b)

def bar2(p):
    a,b=p
    print(a,b)

def wrapper(func,func2):
    a=func()
    func2(a)

wrapper(bar,bar2)
wrapper(foo,foo2)
```

I am searching for a syntax which works with both function pairs to use it in my wrapper code.

EDIT: The definitions of at least foo2 and bar2 should stay this way. Assume that they are from an external library.

Comment: This code does not run because of arg differences. It runs if you use `def foo2(*args):` and `def bar2(*p):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't necessarily agree with the design, but following your requirements in the comments (the function definitions can't change), you can write a wrapper that tries to execute each version (packed vs. unpacked) since it sounds like you might not know what the function expects. The wrapper written below, `argfixer`, does exactly that.

```
def argfixer(func):
    def wrapper(arg):
        try:
            return func(arg)
        except TypeError:
            return func(*arg)
    return wrapper


def foo():
    return 1,2

def bar():
    return (1,2)

@argfixer
def foo2(a,b):
    print(a,b)

@argfixer
def bar2(p):
    a,b=p
    print(a,b)


a = foo()
b = bar()

foo2(a)
foo2(b)

bar2(a)
bar2(b)
```

However, if you aren't able to put the `@argfixer` on the line before the function definitions, you could alternatively wrap them like this in your own script before calling them:

```py
foo2 = argfixer(foo2)
bar2 = argfixer(bar2)
```

And as mentioned in previous comments/answers, `return 1,2` and `return (1,2)` are equivalent and both return a single tuple.

Answer (score 3):

There is no distinction. `return 1,2` returns a tuple. Parentheses do not define a tuple; the comma does. `foo` and `bar` are identical.

As I overlooked until JacobIRR's comment, your problem is that you need to pass an actual tuple, not the unpacked values from a tuple, to `bar2`:

```
a = foo()
foo2(*a)

a = bar()
bar2(a)
```

Comment: That means that there is no possibily to write such a wrapper?

Comment: Not without specifying exactly what the wrapper is supposed to do. Consider a function like `baz(a, b=None)`. Given `a = 1, 2`, both `baz(a)` and `baz(*a)` are legitimate calls. The first passes the arguments `(1,2)` and `None` to `baz`; the second the arguments `1` and `2`.

Comment: It *sounds* like you are trying to write a function that can take *either* a single (non-iterable) value or a sequence of values. Don't do that. Define the function to take an iterable argument, period, and pass an iterable with a single element when necessary.

Comment: You can assume that the called functions have a fixed number of arguments. And i know what the problem is, I am search for a solution which work both cases to write a wrapper.

Comment: So the problem is how to make `wrapper` figure out if the output of its first argument should be unpacked or passed as-is to the second?

Comment: Yes, thats the problem

Comment: The simple solution is, define two wrappers, `pack_wrapper = lambda f, g: g(f())` and `unpack_wrapper = lambda f, g: g(*f())`. That's clearer than the alternative of having to pass an explicit boolean to `wrapper = lambda f, g, unpack: g(*f()) if unpack else g(f())`, and both are clearer than writing code that has to use the `inspect` module to examine `g`'s signature.

Answer (score 0):

The `return 1, 2` and `return (1, 2)` are equivalent. The comma operator just creates a tuple, whether it is enclosed in parentheses or not.

All programming languages that I know of return *a single value*, so, since you want to return multiple, those values must be wrapped into a collection type, in this case, a tuple.

The problem is in the way *you call* the second function. Make it `bar2(a)` instead of `bar2(*a)`, which breaks the tuple into separate arguments.

Answer (score -1):

This code does not run because of `arg` differences. It runs if you use `def foo2(*args):` and `def bar2(*p):`.